# Play multiple audio streams at the same time

Tags: ios, audio, core-media

Currently I managed to play one audio stream successfully. However, when I try to play multiple audio streams at the same time, it sounds VERY bad. Could someone guide me on where I should look?

---

My current code has:

- One AudioQueueRef
- One CMBufferQueueRef
- An AudioQueueBufferRef for each stream

Is this the correct approach?

---

PS: I can add code if needed, however I don't want to just add 150 lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the playback problem.

Turns out, you need:

- One CMBufferQueueRef
- An AudioQueueRef for each stream
- An AudioQueueBufferRef for each stream